# JS Code to scroll a webpage not working

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am trying to automate the scrolling down of the webpage using the following JS code

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

However, instead of scrolling down the page, it is scrolling up.

Webpage in question is - https://www.zeekbeek.com/OSBA/Search-Results#profession=Lawyers&region=OH

Can someone kindly check what's going wrong here

Comment: if it's scrolling up maybe you should check 'scrollHeight' variable whether it is a non-zero value...

Comment: Worked fine on chrome

Comment: Right, working in Chrome but not in FF. I am using the Execute JS addon to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be seen only when the DOM is updated by ajax request or some other javascript. Otherwise, it's working. I think while updating DOM you should use jquery live

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );
```

update the DOM through the live method. I think that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working fine.

**Check out the demo below**

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

```css
.top{
  height: 500px;
  background: orangered;
}

.bottom{
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<button> Scroll down </button>
<div class="top"> </div>
<div class="bottom"> </div>
```